# Validation in DispatchAction in struts 1.2 framework

Tags: java, struts

How can I implement validation in different-2 methods of dispatchaction struts 1.2 framework

Comment: Please, specify the language/framework you're asking the question about, and read faq (http://stackoverflow.com/faq), particularly the section "How Do I ask questions here?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify two different action mappings for this particular dispatch action class. For each mapping you may specify a different validation setting.

```
<action path="/someAction" name="somForm" type="com.examples.SomeDispatchAction />
<action path="/anotherAction" name="anotherForm" type="com.examples.SomeDispatchAction />
```

Note that the same class declares two different action forms named "someForm" and "anotherForm". This way you can specify two different validations set.